# sending images to the back or front - xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I've got a text box and an image. I'm looking for a way to move the image around and within the text box.

The code below generates the necessary parts, but the image is always positioned behind the textbox.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('textbox.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 4
col = 1

# Example
text = 'A simple textbox with some text'
worksheet.insert_textbox(row, col, text)
row += 10
worksheet.insert_image('A1', 'download.png')

workbook.close()
```

**It outputs:**

[image: It outputs:]

**What I need:**

[image: The desired output:]

Comment: I am the author of XlsxWriter. That isn't currently possible and it is unlikely to be added in the future .

Comment: @ jmcnamara Oh, that's unfortunate. I appreciate your reply anyway.